# Sonarqube says: A "NullPointerException" could be thrown; "getFolderPath()" can return null

Tags: java, sonarqube

I get a following bug from sonarqube

> A "NullPointerException" could be thrown; "getFolderPath()" can return
>   null.

for the following line:

```
if (upstreamContent.getFolderPath() != null && !upstreamContent.getFolderPath().isEmpty()) {
   ...
}
```

Where upstreamContent may not be null.

How can I fix it in sonarqube without turning off the rule?

**UPDATE:**

Someone asked me to show the source of UpstreamContent

```
public class UpstreamContent {

    @Nullable
    private String folderPath;

    ...

    @CheckForNull
    @Nullable
    public String getFolderPath() {
        return folderPath;
    }

    public void setFolderPath(String folderPath) {
        this.folderPath = folderPath;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you refreshed the SonarCube analysis? It looks ok to me.

Comment: Can you please tell the type of `upstreamContent`

Comment: "Are you sure you refreshed the SonarCube analysis?" yes I am sure.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Probably by saving the result to a variable rather than making the call twice:

```
String path = upstreamContent.getFolderPath();
if (path != null && !path.isEmpty()) {
   ...
}
```

Maybe you or I know that if it doesn't return `null` the first time, it won't the second (I don't, actually, because I don't know what `upstreamContent` is :-) ), but a general-purpose tool can't know or assume that. For all it knows, it could return non-`null` the first time and `null` the second. By saving the call result to a variable, we ensure that Sonarqube and anyone coming along later to read and maintain the code knows, for sure, that we've done a `null` check before calling `isEmpty`.

In fact, now that you've posted the code for `upstreamContent`'s class, it's entirely possible for `getFolderPath` to return non-`null` for the first call and `null` for the second (if another thread calls `setFolderPath(null)` in-between).

Comment: I think it is usefull, it solves the issue. I think the sonar may thought the getFolderPath() result may vary.

Comment: as one of the developer behind the tool : this is exactly what the symbolic execution engine assumes : two calls to this getter may produce different results, first one being non null and the second one being null.

Comment: @benzonico, how about when it **does not** produce different results? Do you have a `@SuppressWarnings` of some sort? I do not want to deactivate the rule ^^